# Android activity lags after multiple interactions

Tags: java, android

My applications has multiple activities. They work perfectly fine until you decide to open another activity and go back to the last activity and repeat this process. Basically if you go from activity A to B, than go back to A and repeat this the app starts to lag. More specifically the activity A starts to lag until it is refresh. I have checked with leak canary for memory leak but it doesn't seem to be the case.  Any clue about why is this happening?

Comment: You should post your code (how you're opening activities, manifest - that's bare minimum)

Comment: Hi Arianit, please include an [mve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)